# Obtain intermediate variables assignments

Tags: prolog

I am trying to use Prolog to represent state of a room.

I have a set of rules and a set of facts, but sometimes some of the facts are
not defined. For instance, temperature in a room can decrease due to either
cooling or opening a window, but sometimes I do not have a window sensor.

```
% Rules

temperature_trend(decrease) :-
    cooling(on).
temperature_trend(decrease) :-
    window(open).

% Facts

cooling(off).

%window(close).  % Unknown, I do not have a window sensor

% Main

main() :-
    temperature_trend(decrease).
```

If I run this program I would get an `undefined procedure` error. I can deal with
this by explicitly setting the window
status to "anything" with `window(W).` (I programmatically prepare the Prolog
source, so this is quite easy).

Now the query `temperature_trend(decrease)`
would succeed because `window(W)` would lead to `window(open)`. However, in this
case I want to know that `W = open`.

Is there a way to return the variable assignments for this fact? Or maybe am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

Note that the
rule tree could be arbitrarily deep, for instance I could add a new rule `next_temperature(lower) :- temperature_trend(decrease).` and I still
want to know that `next_temperature(lower)` succeeds only by setting `W = open`. Terms are also more complex
because they also have a time index (`T = 232`).

Maybe one option would be to return a list of assignments, which would be empty
if all facts were known.

Comment: Declare `window/1` as dynamic so that `window(X)` query will simply fail if the facts don't exist. `:- dynamic(window/1).`

Comment: Ideally I do not want it to fail if the fact does not exist. I want it tell me it would succeed by adding such fact.

Comment: Well, of course it will succeed by adding such a fact, by definition. So I'm not sure what you mean by that. Without declaring it dynamic, if there's no match to the query via fact or predicate, you get an interpreter error that it doesn't exist. If you declare it dynamic, and make the query, and it doesn't exist, the query simply fails as if the facts/predicates were there, but there was not match. Maybe you need a clearer example shown in your question.

Comment: If I add `window(W).` as a fact, the interpreter will "assign" `W = open` and the query would succeed. I want to know that such "assignment" happened, i.e., that the query would succeed by adding `window(open).` to my facts.

Answer (score 0):

Write a meta-interpreter that gives you what is true, e.g.,

```
prove(Goal, True) :-
    phrase(prove(Goal), True).

prove(true) -->
    !.
prove((A,B)) -->
    !,
    prove(A),
    prove(B).
prove((A;B)) -->
    !,
    (   prove(A)
    ;   prove(B)
    ).
prove(Fact) -->
    [Fact],
    { clause(Fact, Body) },
    prove(Body).
```

Now, given `window(_)`, we get:

```
?- prove(temperature_trend(decrease), L).
L = [temperature_trend(decrease), window(open)].
```

Lots of variations are possible!

Comment: Ideally I would like it to tell me only the "new" facts (so only `window(open)`). However, that is definitely a step in the right direction. I will make some experiments with this.